# Selenium 3.3.1: NoDefClassFound (com.google.common.base.Function)

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have the strangest problem, with Selenium 3.3.1, when trying to start a `ChromeDriver` (or `FirefoxDriver`), with the simplest code:

**Edit**: added the full class

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // testCrawl();
        seleniumGetDoc();
    }

    public static void seleniumGetDoc() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path/to/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); //here something goes terribly wrong
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://google.com/");
        String htmlContent = driver.getPageSource();
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    }
}
```

With the following dependencies in my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I obtain the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at my.package.MyClass.seleniumGetDoc(CrawlerMain.java:28)
    at  my.package.MyClass.main(CrawlerMain.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Nonetheless when downgrading my selenium versions, it works properly with the following dependencies:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Does anyone knows why apparently in the `3.3.1` version some guava library is missing? Or have I missed something in setting up Selenium?

I have looked at several posts on StackOverflow, however the problem is either linked to the missing installation of external jars (which maven should handle) or to the dependency missing of `selenium-server`.

**Edit** my list of dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Also when running `mvn dependency:tree`, maven indicates that only *selenium-java* depends on `com.google.guava:guava:jar:21.0:compile`

**Edit** adding my dependency tree:

```
[INFO] org.linkedin.crawler:main:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.10.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:21.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-opera-driver:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:htmlunit-driver:jar:2.24:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:3.3.1:compile (version selected from constraint [2.53.0,4.0.0))
[INFO] |     |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.24:compile
[INFO] |        +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |        +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |        +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.23:compile
[INFO] |        +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:neko-htmlunit:jar:2.24:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |        |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |        +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.21:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |        +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.2.20.v20161216:compile
[INFO] |           +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.20.v20161216:compile
[INFO] |           +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.20.v20161216:compile
[INFO] |           \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.2.20.v20161216:compile
[INFO] |              \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.2.20.v20161216:compile
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.48:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:jetty-repacked:jar:9.4.1.v20170120:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.8:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
```

**Update**: It works with `selenium-server` with version 3.3.1 and `selenium-java` version 3.0.1, from `selenium-java` version >3.1.x it starts breaking with the same afore mentioned error

**Edit** Adding my full pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.main.groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>main</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>my.main.Class</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*log4j*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I've seen similar issues with a large code base. I'm assuming that selenium isn't your only dependency. Can you post the others? If you can't, try running `mvn dependency:tree` and look for what version of guava you have in your class path.

Comment: @AaronDavis I would have thought the same, but I cannot identify any other dependency I have depending on guava besides selenium (see my edit). Needless to say, the guava library is present in my classpath, however the "not found" function is definitely not present

Comment: Could you point out `at my.package.MyClass.seleniumGetDoc(CrawlerMain.java:28)` in your code and also share the imports used in this class. I don't find where are you using the class `Function`.

Comment: I think something is wrong with `TimeUnit` import. It's supposed to be from JDK imported as `import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;` Try to command/alt click on it and see if it opens something else, when you use 2.45.0.

Comment: @nullpointer See my edit I added the imports. Actually I am not using the `Function` class library, it is however a dependency of `selenium-java`.

Comment: @KirilS. Not sure why something would be wrong with `TimeUnit` as the one I used is from the package `java.util.concurrent`, and the error happens before the line using it is ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having similar issues, and narrowed it down to including both Selenium 3.3.1 Standalone and HTMLUnit-driver-standalone 2.21.  Turns out I didn't need the HTMLUnit jar at all.  It's already included in 3.3.1 dependencies.  (If I remember right the last version did not include HTMLUnit which is why I had added it separately before... this may explain the > 3.01 part.)

Now, I don't use the Selenium-java part... just the standalone server, but it looks like you have 2 HTMLUnit versions... 2.24 and 2.23 in your dep list so it could be a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Leaving this as an answer since it is too long for a comment. I tried to reproduce your issue and it is working fine for me. Is there something else you have added to your class path somewhere? Are you running from an IDE or from a maven command at the command line? Also what version of chrome are you using and do you have the correct chromedriver version for your chrome version?

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

I used this test code:

```
package com.foo;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SeleniumTest {

    @Test
    public void testFoo() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "MY_CHROMEDRIVER_PATH");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://google.com/");
        String htmlContent = driver.getPageSource();
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        System.out.println(htmlContent);
        Thread.sleep(2_000);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

And this pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Fair point, I was using Eclipse. So I built it through Maven, and keep getting the same error running it with `java` on the command line. I use the latest chromedriver (2.28), and my Chrome version is 57.0.2987.110. I don't think the OS matters, but for the record I am running a Linux debian distribution. DOn't think the JVM is an issue but for the record as well I am running: `openjdk version "1.8.0_121"`. I checked what's on my classpath but I can't find anything out of the ordinary (even removing everything besides selenium did not help ...)

Comment: The strangest thing is that when creating my jar, I copy the dependencies in a lib directory, and `guava-21.0.jar` is present in there... Don't know what to think of this...

Comment: @asettouf can you post your whole Pom so I can see if it works on my machine to rule out some weird plugin settings?

Comment: @asettouf Hmm, well. I don't like this as an answer but I have tried it out on my machine with your full pom file and ran the App class successfully in my IDE. I can only think at this point it is something to do with some version of your libraries (openjdk, maven, etc).

My system details:

 MacBook Pro, Google Chrome: Version 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit), Chrome WebDriver: Version 2.28, Java: Oracle javac 1.8.0_121, Maven: Apache Maven Version 3.2.5, IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1

Comment: No worries, I agree that it's pretty strange given that it doesn't happen on your side. Thanks for helping though, and at least proving that my code is not wrong, but rather some weird configuration somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 different versions of guava.jar in my classpath which caused this issue, removing the older version from my classpath did the trick.

Comment: Fair point, however I only have one version of guava which is pulled by selenium